# Relative black hole?

Tags: black-hole, special-relativity

When some object is moving, it appears smaller and more massive. What if it's moving so fast it should become a black hole? Some calculations:

Let observed radius $R_0\gamma$ ($R_0$ - radius at rest) be equal Schwarzschild radius for object with observed mass $M_0\gamma$ ($M_0$ - mass at rest):

$$R_0 / \gamma = \frac{2GM_0\gamma}{c^2}$$

$$\gamma^2=\frac{R_0c^2}{2GM_0}$$

$$\frac{v}{c}=\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM_0}{R_0c^2}}$$

For Earth it gives $v=0.999999999304c$ and for Sun $v=0.999997877903c$. Is my reasoning correct? How would we see such objects?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before on SE. The Schwarzschildt solution only applies to a mass at rest (in the references frame in which its calculated). If an object at high velocity could collapse into a BH, then for reasons of symmetry you would be able to make any object collapse simply by moving past it at high velocity.

Comment: @pela - - but why would that be strange?  we live in a universe where *causality itself* (for hell's sake!) is totally relative

Comment: @JoeBlow: Hmm… _simultaneity_ is relative, but causality isn't. If event A is the cause of event B for some observer, then A precedes B for all inertial observers. The laws of physics should be the same for all observers. If observer A is at rest with respect to some star and concludes that pressure and gravity is in equilibrium, then to observer B, traveling nearly at the speed of light, _must_ conclude the same. For instance, in the reference frame of the [Oh-My-God particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle), everything should collapse into black holes, which hasn't happened

Comment: (simultaneity is relative, but causality isn't - sorry :O )   But surely it would just be the case that, the speedy observor sees a black hole; others do not see a black hole.  What's the problem with that man?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer quickly, the answer is that **no**, an object cannot be made to collapse as such.

There are multiple reasons as to why. Pela brings up a great argument here, reminding us that if a black hole *could* be formed this way, then I could be made to collapse into a black hole just by something moving by me at extreme velocities. Clearly, this cannot occur.

To understand why this is, we must first completely throw away the idea you have of [relativistic mass](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/mass.html). The entire concept of relativistic mass was created to allow for [Newtonian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics) to still hold in relativistic situations. By modifying the mass of an object at extreme velocities, equations such as $F=ma$ can be made to still hold. To paraphrase [Philip Gibbs](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_fast.html), gravity couples not only to mass but also to momentum and itself. Therefore, a description of spacetime in the vicinity of an object will be incomplete without momentum considerations. From this [relativistic momentum](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relmom.html#c1), we can compute the [relativistic energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/releng.html).

While these quantities are useful for giving detailed descriptions of the body, the answer is actually somewhat simpler. We must remember that an object must behave the same in all inertial reference frames. If the object does not become a black hole in its own frame (as it clearly will not), then it cannot appear to be one in any other.

If you are wondering how to reconcile this with a relativistic mass that approaches infinity, the answer is simply that relativistic mass is not real mass. The metrics which describe spacetime in the vicinity of these objects refer to the [invariant mass](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mass.html#mas), which is the rest mass of the body.